# Multiline Inline Entry Element for QuickDialog

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, quickdialog

QMultilineElement pushes a new controller with a UITextView in it. There are some times, however, when inline editing is preferable. Has anyone made a custom element for QuickDialog that serves this purpose?

Project: http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline editing, use QEntryElement.

https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/blob/master/quickdialog/QEntryElement.h

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: EZForm has support for multiline inline fields: https://github.com/chrismiles/EZForm